# There is a ring with multiplication. Can we find a formula for division based on formula for multiplication?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, division-algebras, division-rings, divergent-integrals

Studying divergent integrals, I [found](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403727/10059) a good formula for their multiplication:

$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\cdot\int_0^\infty g(x)dx=\int_0^\infty D^2 \Delta^{-1} \left(\Delta D^{-2}f(x)\cdot\Delta D^{-2}g(x)\right) dx +D \Delta^{-1} \left(\Delta D^{-2}f(x)\cdot\Delta D^{-2}g(x)\right)|_{x=0},$

where $\Delta D^{-2}f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\int_0^s f(t)\,dt\,ds$.

Here is the Mathematica code:

```
f[x_] := x
g[x_] := x

Func := D[
    D[Sum[(DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]), x], x], x]
Const := (D[
     Sum[(DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]), x], x] /. x -> 0) 
Inactivate[
 Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
   g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

Out:=$\int _0^{\infty }xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }xdx=\int_0^{\infty } \left(x^3-\frac{x}{6}\right)
dx+\frac{1}{180}$

The code fails only when Mathematica's discrete or conventional integrator fails to provide closed form answer. Thus, the formula even if fails to produce a closed form, still defines the product.

That said, I wonder, whether having the formula for multiplication we can derive a formula for division, particularly, for reciprocals of some divergent integrals, such as $1/\int_0^\infty dx$. Can we solve an equation

$W\int_0^\infty dx =1$

for $W$ based on this multiplication formula?

Comment: Before you worry about division, maybe you should first think about whether you have a ring structure.

Comment: @Kimball can you please explain your concerns, all ring axioms seem to be satisfied.