# What are the properties of this set of infinite matrices and operations on them?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices

Consider infinite matrices of the form

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & . \\
 0 & a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & . \\
 0 & 0 & a_0 & a_1 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a_0 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The elements on each diagonal coincide.

My questions are:

- Do they form a commutative ring?
- Can they be extended to form a field?

Now, let define an operation $\operatorname{reg} A=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k a_k,$

where $B_k$ are Bernoulli numbers.

What are the properties of this operation?

Let's define another operation $\det' A=\exp(\Re \operatorname{reg} \log A)$.

What are the properties of this operation?

**Motivation part.**

This is meant to be a matrix representation of divergent integrals and series.
For instance,

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1/12 & 1/2 & 1/2  & 0 & . \\
 0 & 1/12 & 1/2 & 1/2 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 1/12 & 1/2 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/12 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\int_0^\infty x dx=\int_0^\infty \frac 2{x^3}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1/6 & 1/2 & 1/2  & 0 & . \\
 0 & 1/6 & 1/2 & 1/2 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/2 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

There are also some expressions that include divergent integrals that can be represented this way:

$(-1)^{\int_0^\infty dx}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 i & -\pi  & -\frac{i \pi ^2}{2} & \frac{\pi ^3}{6} & \frac{i \pi ^4}{24} & -\frac{\pi
   ^5}{120} & . \\
 0 & i & -\pi  & -\frac{i \pi ^2}{2} & \frac{\pi ^3}{6} & \frac{i \pi ^4}{24} & . \\
 0 & 0 & i & -\pi  & -\frac{i \pi ^2}{2} & \frac{\pi ^3}{6} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & i & -\pi  & -\frac{i \pi ^2}{2} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & -\pi  & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The $\operatorname{reg}$ operation gives the regularized value of the integral or series.

Comment: Could you add some motivation for the parts of the question on Bernoulli polynomials?

Comment: @MarkWildon yes, just a moment.

Comment: @MarkWildon done. By the way, a typo: it's Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, but I still don't understand the motivation. How does one use Bernoulli numbers to express the definite integral as a matrix / formal power series? Could you give an explicit example of the summation? Is it using Euler's summation formula?

Comment: @MarkWildon Bernoulli numbers are used for regularization. The integrals can be transformed using these formulas: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403704/an-operation-is-defined-on-polynomials-how-do-i-generalize-it-to-other-classes If you have a MathML-enabled browser (Firefox-based), here is my wiki: https://exnumbers.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page#Relations_between_standard_parts_of_trigonometric_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions Also, look here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Comment: @MarkWildon and if you are wondering where it all comes from, it is more based on Faulhaber's formula (it exactly uses Bernoulli numbers for summation). It also can be derived from Ramanujan's summation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the matrices have entries from a (unital) ring $R$ then the set of such matrices is isomorphic to $R[[x]]$, the ring of formal power series over $R$. To see this, observe that the map sending the infinite matrix with $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$ and $a_k = 0$ for $k \ge 2$ to $x$ is a ring isomorphism.

This also answers the second question: if $R$ is an integral domain then set of matrices embeds canonically in the field of fractions of $R[[x]]$ and this is the smallest field containing $R[[x]]$. In particular, if $R$ is a field then this field is $\{ \sum_{k=-m}^\infty a_k x^k : a_k \in R, m \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$.

I'm uncertain how $\mathrm{reg}$ is (well)-defined, but certainly one can take $R$ to be the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ and then something like $\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k(z) x^k$ is a well-defined element of $R[[x]] = \mathbb{C}[z][[x]]$. If, as in the correction then one wants Bernoulli numbers rather than the polynomials, just specialize to $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ by evaluating at $z=0$.

Comment: Yes, I came to this from formal power series. The entries are complex numbers. The matrices represent divergent integrals.