# What's the regularized value of these divergent integrals: $\int_0^\infty \ln x \, dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: regularization, divergent-integrals

When playing with divergent integrals $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ and their transformations with operators $\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x) \, dx$ and $\int_0^\infty\frac1x\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t[ f(t)](x) \, dx$, which preserve the area under the curve (that is, the values of the integrals), and as such, define the equivalence classes of divergent integrals, I have arrived at these interesting results:

$1.\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} \, dx=\gamma +2 H$

$2.\int_0^\infty \log (x) \, dx=\tau  (H-\gamma-1)$

$3. \int_0^\infty \frac{\log (x)}{x} \, dx=-\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\gamma  H$

$4. \int_0^\infty \frac{\log (x)}{x^2} \, dx=(2-H) \tau$

where $H=\int_1^\infty \frac1x \, dx$ and $\tau=\int_0^\infty dx$, are simpler divergent integrals, with the regularized value $0$.

It follows thus, that the regularized value of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log (x)}{x} \, dx$ is $-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}$. On the other hand, the regularized value of $H\tau$ is a mystery for me and I do not know whether one constant can be expressed via the other. As such, the regularized values of integrals $(2)$ and $(4)$ are unknown, except they should be equal by modulus but of the opposite sign.

I tried Borel and other kinds of regularization on the both in Mathematica, with no results so far. I am very curious, what the regularized value could be.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: Can you make this question more self-contained by explaining what is meant by the value of a divergent integral?

Comment: @MichaelHardy equivalence class of divergent integrals.

Comment: Under what conditions are two divergent integrals considered "equivalent"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403704/an-operation-is-defined-on-polynomials-how-do-i-generalize-it-to-other-classes

Comment: Now I know that the integrals (2) and (4) have regularized value zero.